# How to convert textbox value ddmmyyyy to dd-mm-yyyy?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, datetime-format

I have a textbox in my project where user enters date, like `ddmmyyyy`. I need to convert it to `dd-mm-yyyy` format so that I could fetch particular data from database.

Comment: Really having a datetime in string format is bad. Use any date picker control that can get datetime from user and persist it as UTC.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your `string` to `DateTime` first and then generate it's string representation with *that* format.

For example;

```
var s = "11062016";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

By the way, I *assume* you wanna say `MM` instead of `mm` since `mm` specifier is for minutes but `MM` specifier is for months.

On the other hand, you never told the data you wanna fetch but, it is not a good idea to get `DateTime` values (if they are) with strings. Use DateTime values to get DateTime data from your database (which most of of RDMS supports), not strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string str = "06112016";
DateTime date = new DateTime();
DateTime.TryParseExact(str, "ddMMyyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
string FormattedDate = date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
```